# PHP always reports SQL success even when it fails

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is a simple one, maybe I'm having a long brain fart or something, but whats happening is the form is used to set a record only if the name and their cpukey matches then it will continue, as this is a public page with no login, it would be rather annoying for people to be changing other peoples things without knowing 2 sets in information. So the problem here is, the function itself actually works flawlessly, the Message produced which states SUCCESS or FAILURE always produces SUCCESS, even if the function failed (due to no match on one or more rows)

Here is the code used.

```
if(isset($_POST['upduserNotify'])){
    $ccurrentname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ccnameVal']); 
    $cclientnotify = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cnotifyVal']);
    $cclientcpuk = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ccpukeyVal']);

    $changenot = "UPDATE clients SET notify = '$cclientnotify' WHERE cpukey = '$cclientcpuk' AND name = '".$_POST['ccnameVal']."'";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $changenot)) {
        echo'<div align ="center" style="color:#000000">Your Custom notification was updated successfully</div><br />';
    } else {
        echo'<div align ="center">You entered an incorrect CPUKEY/Name or used an invalid character</div><br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got a dangerous SQL injection hole there, where you use `$_POST['ccnameVal']` directly in the query. You should strongly consider switching to parameterized queries, instead of all the `mysqli_real_escape_string` stuff.

Comment: I had it set to a mysql_real_escape_string(), I was testing things and left it there, but that will be fixed with the problem of the reporting. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I will be working on the parameterized or PDO in next updating. I have used a vulnerability scanner and it has been reported safe, so far.

Comment: Any idea why it always reports "Your Custom notification was updated successfully" even while the data is not sent?

Comment: My answer covers that question.

Comment: Sorry, it was not there when I made that comment, lol.

Answer (score 1):

An `UPDATE` query that runs, but finds no rows to update, is still a *successful* one - it ran to completion without encountering any errors, so `mysqli_query` will return `TRUE`, [per the docs](http://php.net/mysqli_query). (If it were a `SELECT` sort of query, it'd return a `mysqli_result` object.)

If you want to do something different when it didn't find any rows to update, you'll want to look at [the number of affected rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) and act accordingly.

Comment: I just want to have it say one of the two messages if the data was sent or not, I'm looking into that seeing what I can use, thanks. I will report back with my findings.

Comment: @JohnMartin It should be as simple as `if (mysqli_query($con, $changenot) && mysqli_affected_rows() > 0) {`

Comment: if (mysqli_query($con, $changenot) && mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0 )

Now it produces same problem, only now reports FAILURE even when successful. omg lol.

Comment: I changed it to == 1 then added else if == 0 to the fail message, it works, :)

Thanks for the help. I'm pretty good with the coding, just need to learn the use of all functions. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
        if(isset($_POST['upduserNotify'])){
            $ccurrentname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ccnameVal']); 
            $cclientnotify = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cnotifyVal']);
            $cclientcpuk = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ccpukeyVal']);

        $changenot = "UPDATE `clients` SET `notify` = '$cclientnotify' WHERE `cpukey` = '$cclientcpuk' AND `name` = '$ccurrentname'";

                if (mysqli_query($con, $changenot) && mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1 )
                {
                    echo'<div align ="center" style="color:#000000">Your Custom Xnotify was updated successfully</div><br />';
                } 
                else if (mysqli_query($con, $changenot) && mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 0 )
                {
                    echo'<div align ="center">You entered an incorrect CPUKEY/Name or used an invalid character</div><br />';
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is going to run your query twice if it gets to the `else if`. There are better ways of doing this.

Comment: I'm in the process of converting everything to PDO so I will re-evaluate all this later one. Thanks for the help.